# Adobe Analytics- Time between first cart addition and check-out

Tags: adobe-analytics

On adobe analytics, how do I see what the first item added to a customer's cart was and the time between when the first cart item was added and when the customer checked-out?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you be able to post your code and explain what you have tried so far?

Comment: Currently there isn't any native functionality / reporting for this sort of thing, but it has been asked many times by users. If you go here,  https://forums.adobe.com/ideas/9814  there is a comment pointing to some code to help implement this sort of tracking.